# SQL where clause with value computed from a query

Tags: sql

I'd like to do something along the lines of

`select * from table where column < myValue`,

and `myValue` is obtained by

`select myValue from table where id = @id --there should only be one.`

How can I combine these?

I tried where in, but with no success.

Comment: 2 different tables or the same? And I'm assuming that myValue is numeric field?

Comment: @ingo: same table. actually, this is a slight simplification from the problem at hand.  the column is a datetime column, and so the value should also be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
declare @myValue int -- value type
select top(1) @myValue = myValue from table where id = @id --there should only be one.
select * from table where column < ISNULL(@myValue,0);
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use a JOIN.

```
select t1.* from mytable as t1 
join mytable as t2 on t1.column < t2.myValue
where t2.id = @id
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple subquery should be fine.

```
select * from table where column < (select myValue from table where id = @id LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: for some reason this didn't work for me.  i think perhaps because myValue and column are really the same column name.  also, it didn't like the limit syntax.

Comment: Entirely possible :) Can you provide sample table and column names and I'll throw together something working for you?

Comment: @user420667: Maybe is not workin becasue you are using sqlserver and this syntax is for mysql (sqlserver don't have "limit", use instead top 1)